Either $G\setminus e$ or $G/e$ is nonseparable?
Let $G$ be a nonseparable graph and let $e$ be an edge in it. We want to show that $G/e$ (obtained by contracting $e$) is nonseparable or $G\setminus e$ (obtained by deleting $e$) is nonseparable.
I am stuck as I am trying to show that if both of these graphs are separable then $G$ must be separable. Here is what I got so far, it might be close or it might be that I should use a completely different approach or theorem; 
Checking for loops we may assume that $G$ is loopless, let $u, v$ be the end vertices of $e$, then either $u$ or $v$ is a cut vertex (a separating vertex is a cut vertex here), assume WLOG that $u$ is a cut vertex. 
On the other hand, looking at the other graph, $G/e$, $u$ and $v$ are joined to form a vertex $w$, since if any other vertex is separating of $G/e$ it will make $G$ separable, we may assume that $w$ is the only separating vertex of $G/e$. This means that $V(H)\cap V(K)= \{w\}$ for nonempty subgraphs H and K of $G/e$.
Can we deduce from the situation at hand that $G$ is separable ? We can draw it and see it must be separable but a drawing is not a proof.

Do you have an example of where contraction leads to a disconnected graph?

Show that if $G$ is non separable and the retraction is separable, then the cut vertex is the newly contracted edge. Now go back to $G$ and argue that if that's the case, said edge was irrelevant for connectivity

Won't the first option always be true?
I've found a characterization which says nonseparable iff any two edges lie on a common cycle ( https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/~mabfchen/Math4821B/Nonseparable%20Graphs.pdf ).
So if we contract and edge, any two edges that were on a common cycle will still be in a common cycle (which might be the same, or one whith one edge less), hence the new graph is also nonseparable. But I might be missing something.

Your logic does not hold for small cycles. In particular, consider $K_4^-$ i.e. $K_4$ without an edge. This is a $2$-connected graph, but if you contract the diagonal edge, you get $P_2$ which is $1$-connected (I'm assuming contracting an edge doesn't create multiple edges, but if it did it's still $1$-connected)

Yeah, you are absolutely right. Didn't think about it long enough.
